# Visual Studio 2015 - NuGet package removes all project references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I just tried to install the CefSharp.WinForms package through NuGet on Visual Studio 2015, and it removed all my project references, making my Solution Explorer show errors on them all. For some reason I cannot add these references back in - in the 'Add Reference' window, if I select references to add, they simply don't take effect and are unchecked when I next open the window. I don't think this is a problem the the actual package, as I have searched and searched and have not seen anything like this on the web. Help please!

Thanks in advance,

-Matthew

Comment: do you get an error when trying to add the reference?

Comment: No error appears - it looks like it worked, but it causes no changes in the  project.

Comment: Have you checked out the `Post Install` steps in the `Readme.txt` that opens after you install the `Nuget` packages? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/47/NuGet/Readme.txt#L7 Also would have been helpful if you had tagged this with `CefSharp`, only see this as I occasionally look at `chromium-embedded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the platform to x86 or x64 in Configuration Manager then the references will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same thing, I feel your pain.
I didn't manage to resolve it, but I did manage to get my project back by simply uninstalling all the CEF nuget packages in the package manager, then all the missing references magically reappeared!

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling is an answer to the question.

Comment: Apologies, but in addition to sympathizing with the OP I also included the info that uninstalling the nuget packages fixed the problem..  (Thanks for the backup, mob)